# How to start Pantheon from the command line

Tags: command-line, xorg, lightdm, pantheon

Long story as to why I've chosen to go this route, but I've installed Ubuntu Trusty without a desktop, and then installed *pantheon, pantheon-shell, pantheon-greeter* and *elementary-desktop* packages.

The question is: how do I now start the desktop from the command line?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The typical route to starting X from the command line (TTY) is to use `.xinitrc` and/or `startx`.

First, find out which command starts the Pantheon session. Look in `/usr/share/xsessions` for a `.desktop` file named after Pantheon, and check the `Exec` line in that file:

```
$ grep Exec -R /usr/share/xsessions/pantheon.desktop
Exec=gnome-session --session=pantheon
```

For a one-time run, you can do:

```
startx /usr/bin/gnome-session --session=pantheon
```

For a long-term setting, use `.xinitrc`. Usually, you wouldn't have an `.xinitrc` present. So, create one containing:

```sh
#! /bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/gnome-session --session=pantheon
```

Then run `startx`.

Check the Arch Wiki article on [`.xinitrc`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xinitrc) to see how to make more a full-fledged one.

Comment: Nice answer. I don't understand why it hasn't been upvoted more

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're missing a desktop manager to start X. [LightDM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM) is the most common these days. Easy to install:

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

Then you can reboot (and it'll load up automatically) or you can start it there and then if it doesn't already do this after install:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```