# Running two sessions of Cinnamon

Tags: desktop-environments, cinnamon, session

maybe this is a stupid question, but is it possible to run two sessions of a desktop envoirement at the same time (preferrably Cinnamon) and be able to switch between them like you can switch between terminal sessions with `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `(F1,F2,F3)` ?

I have a screen and a beamer and I want to either run the presentation on the beamer (notes on the mainscreen) OR the screen magnifier on the beamer (and the demonstrated program on the main screen).
I can already do that with one session of cinnamon, but it requires a few clicks and that is somewhat unprofessional and I figured that I rather ask a dumb question than breaking my cinnamon by doing something dumb.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** It's much easier than that.
Just add the workspaces applet to your taskbar and you can switch between workspaces. I don't know why I hadn't thought about that earlier...
I will not delete it in case someone else doesn't think of the workspaces.

Comment: If you have an answer, than write an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While workspaces are the way to go here, I'll still answer the original question. It's not hard to run multiple instances of X - the system that actually is the GUI. You just need to use `startx` (and optionally `.xinitrc`). See [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/629329/158442) for a quick intro to using it, and the Arch Wiki article on `.xinitrc` for more complete information.

On each TTY you want to run Cinnamon on, you just need to do:

```
startx /usr/bin/gnome-session --session=cinnamon
```

Then switch between them the way you normally would switch to the corresponding TTY.