# Possible to run graphical sessions on multiple TTYs?

Tags: xorg, users, tty

On a default Ubuntu (15.04) installation, We have 7 TTYs that we can switch with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1 (or F2 - F7)</kbd>, where TTY1-6 are terminals and TTY7 is the graphical X session.

I would like to have more than one TTY with graphical login, so e.g. make TTY6 an additional GUI terminal.

Is this possible and if yes, how do I set it up and are there restrictions (like don't log into the same account graphically twice)? And when I manually start an x session in a TTY, how do I quit that graphical session again afterwards and revert the TTY back to a terminal?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/631052/158442? Or do you want to run a display manager in each TTY?

Comment: Take a look [Here](http://x.sodpit.com/multix.htm).

Comment: I just run `startx $(which gnome-shell)` in any tty.

Comment: @Serg If I try this, I get a desktop without Unity. I experienced an error a few days ago that Unity stopped starting and I had to reinstall and reenable it in CCSM. Will I have to do this every time? Besides, it does not work as it should, Unity seems not to restart but crash. In TTY7, everything is ok again though.

Comment: @ByteCommander well, yeah, because in that command I basically call Gnome  desktop. Tried replacing that with Unity ?  like `startx $(which unity)` ? I've got 15.04 , so trying to start unity like that kinda breaks, because I don't see indicators in the upper panel, but  on my other laptop with 14.04 it worked alright.

Comment: @Serg Too bad I actually use 15.04 and therefore am also missing my panel indicators... If you find any fix for this, you know who to tell! ;)

Comment: And unity looks really bad. It got some kind of Windows 98 theme....